# Does Java 1.7 use a different character encoding?

Tags: java

We are migrating our application from Java 1.6 to Java 1.7. We recompiled the code using Java 1.7 and received an error while compiling which was due to a character (an `Ó`).

Was there a change in Java 1.7 related to characters? Our application does a lot of processing of incoming files to then load them into a database and I want to ensure that when we upgrade to Java 1.7 that the reading of a file from java and the writing to the database of that content wont result in some odd character conversions.

Do I need to be concerned at all when upgrading to 1.7? If so, how to I get the same encoding that we had in Java 1.6?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.7.html

Comment: Some more context would be helpful. How exactly are you compiling? `javac`? Or Eclipse? Which character exactly was troublesome? The `Ó`? Which error exactly? How about the other diacritic and "special" characters like `Ä` and so on? What character encoding are the source files saved in? This problem can hardly have influence in processing files, as long as you explicitly mention the character encoding everywhere instead of relying on platform default one, e.g. by using `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter` instead of `FileReader` and `FileWriter`.

Comment: Remove that character and forget.

Comment: @RomanC: Please stop italicizing API/library/framework/product names in suggested edits.

Comment: compiling using javac and ant (note, in case it helps, this is Oracle's 1.7)

Comment: @BalusC Did you mean to remove BestPractices' edit?

Comment: @AHungerArtist: no, the suggested edit of RomanC which was rejected twice, but then silently approved by BestPractices because he wanted to edit his own question. See also the edit history.

Comment: @BalusC Ah, I see the information he added was moved elsewhere. That was my only concern.

Comment: Can someone please clarify-- is there a difference between how Java handles character encoding in source code versus character encoding of data it might process e.g. in a running java application?

Answer (score 4):

The error occurs because you've told the Java compiler that your source is UTF-8 encoded, but it still contains some ISO-8859-1 extended characters.  I recently had to fix similar errors in a codebase that was migrated from 1.5 to 1.6.  I believe that Java 7 is much stricter about UTF-8 encoding than previous versions and will issue errors where previously the incorrect encodings were silently accepted.

You will need to make sure that your source code is "Unicode-clean", that is, you must replace any extended ISO-8859-1 characters with their Unicode equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on Windows and discovered that the default encoding for 1.7 was `CP-1252`. I was able to get clean compiles by setting to following environment variable...

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```