# illegal character \187 javac

Tags: java, jdk1.7

I have source code that compiles ok under Java 1.6 but not under java 1.7:

```
addText( indent, NBSP + '»' + NBSP );
```

The compiler throws up the following error:

```
<message priority="warn"><![CDATA[C:\Build\Nightly\trunk\server\src\uk\co\stasys\ier\reports\capability\CapabilityReport.java:411: error: unclosed character literal]]></message>
<message priority="warn"><![CDATA[            addText( indent, NBSP + 'Â»' + NBSP );]]></message>
<message priority="warn"><![CDATA[                                    ^]]></message>
<message priority="warn"><![CDATA[C:\Build\Nightly\trunk\server\src\uk\co\stasys\ier\reports\capability\CapabilityReport.java:411: error: illegal character: \187]]></message>
<message priority="warn"><![CDATA[            addText( indent, NBSP + 'Â»' + NBSP );]]></message>
<message priority="warn"><![CDATA[                                      ^]]></message>
<message priority="warn"><![CDATA[C:\Build\Nightly\trunk\server\src\uk\co\stasys\ier\reports\capability\CapabilityReport.java:411: error: unclosed character literal]]></message>
<message priority="warn"><![CDATA[            addText( indent, NBSP + 'Â»' + NBSP );]]></message>
<message priority="warn"><![CDATA[                                       ^]]></message>
```

It also compiles ok via IntelliJ IDEA using java 1.7.

Comment: My guess is that it's picking up different encodings. I suggest you specify the encoding explicitly on the command line.

Comment: I think Jon is right, if you are using Eclipse, try going to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace and change "Text File Encoding" to UTF-8 (you might have to touch the offending file and save it again)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405775/does-java-1-7-use-a-different-character-encoding?

Comment: Resolved by putting the characters in double quotes not single quotes